# Cache Images in tableviewcontroller

Tags: ios, uitableview, nscache

I would like to save images into the cache in TableViewcontroller. I wrote the following code, but cacheImage is always nil.

```
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSCache *imageCache;
@synthesize imageCache;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.imageCache = [[NSCache alloc] init];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"BebasNeue" size:24];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UIImage *cachedImage = [imageCache objectForKey:@"indexObject"];

    if (cachedImage) {
          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
              cell.imageView.image = cachedImage;
                });
         }
    else {


    NSString *imageURLString=[[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"picture"];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageURLString];
        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
        UIImage *tmpImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UITableViewCell *newsCell = [self.grillMenuTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            [imageCache setObject:tmpImage forKey:@"indexObject"];
            if (newsCell)
            {
                newsCell.imageView.image=tmpImage;
                [newsCell setNeedsLayout];
            }
        });


    });
    }
    return cell;
}
```

I used the following code as Joe advise, but still cell.imageview.image always nil.

```
 NSString *imageURLString=[[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"picture"];
    [[DLImageLoader sharedInstance] loadImageFromUrl:imageURLString
                                           completed:^(NSError *error, UIImage *imgData) {
                                               cell.imageView.image = imgData;
                                               }];
```

Comment: Are you sure that the image actually loads from this URL? It `tmpImage` in `dispatch_async` initialized?

Comment: Yes, I am sure, it loads perfectly fine. But I want cache them to save user data plan and make it much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't try to reinvent the wheel. You should use an external library to do that, there are some great examples. Take a look at [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), it does exactly what you want.

Using it, you can forget queues, manually caching... Just import the header:

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
```

and, in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, you can just set the image into the `UIImageView` with the `setImageWithURL:` (or any of its variants: with placeholders, etc.) method provided by the library:

```
NSString* imageURL = [[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"picture"];
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]];
```

That's all. The library takes care of everything for you. If you want to somehow manage the cache behind this and configure it, you can, using the `SDWebImageManager` class (more info in the GitHub page).

Comment: I have implemented the way that you have advised but it does not return the image. here is the code and another question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23725663/sdwebimagemanager-image-not-loaded-into-tableviewcontroller

Comment: @user1724168 take a look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23725663/sdwebimagemanager-image-not-loaded-into-tableviewcontroller/23731079#23731079, it's the same I wrote in this question.

Comment: @user1724168 have you tried both solutions? If they work, please mark them as correct answers so that others can see it

Answer (score 1):

Here is the tutorial you can follow.
Without Using any third party.
https://sweettutos.com/2015/12/31/swift-how-to-asynchronously-download-and-cache-images-without-relying-on-third-party-libraries/