# SDWebImageManager image not loaded into TableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using SDWebImageImagemanger to hadnle asyn call and caching. However it does not return the image to the cell.imageview.view. Here is the code:

```
        NSString *imageURLString=[[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"picture"];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageURLString];
        SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
        [manager downloadWithURL:url
                         options:0
                        progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize)
         {
             // progression tracking code
         }
                       completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished)
         {
             if (image)
             {
                 cell.imageView.image = image;
             }
         }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use it this way:

```
NSString* imageURL = [[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"picture"];
[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]];
```

For that, first import the category:

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
```

Please note that you don't use the manager at all, you just use the `UIImageView+WebCache` category provided by the library, which gives you the `setImageWithURL:` method. There are other variants of the method which allows you to keep track of the download process, a completion handler, etc.

Comment: I have just tried , it works fine but it is loading images when user sees the tableviewcontroller. Actually I want images to be loaded first and then user sees.

Comment: So you should use the manager to download them (it will cache them) before displaying them, but you should never assume that images will be successfully loaded at time

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23742210/download-data-first-then-show-it-on-tableviewcontroller

Comment: Take a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23742210/download-data-first-then-show-it-on-tableviewcontroller/23743395#23743395

Comment: You should either accept the answer if you consider it answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23724551/cache-images-in-tableviewcontroller/23724767#23724767 or remove the question

Comment: By the way, do you have any idea about the following question that I have posted , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23744176/route-tracing-mapkit-in-ios